# weblogic certificate import issue

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, soa, weblogic12c

I am using jdk 1.8 for weblogic 12.2.1.3 with the SOA suite. I have to import one certificate from the webserver to the application server. I have downloaded the certificate from the webserver and tried to import it in default `cacerts`. Path is `/u01/oracle/products/jdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

My certificate is imported as I am getting a message saying certificate is added. But when i am trying to call the soap URL I am getting an error as below

```
<bpelFault><faultType>0</faultType><remoteFault xmlns="http://schemas.oracle.com/bpel/extension"><part name="summary"><summary>oracle.fabric.common.FabricInvocationException: Unable to invoke endpoint URI "https://stageosb.au.ar/restricted/soasession" successfully due to: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Message send failed: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

So I went to check the certificate I have imported by listing them with alias name with below command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit | grep "Alias name:"
```

I got list of certificates installed. In that list I saw my certificate also mentioned there with one weird thing: All certificates installed from previously have `jdk` at the end. But for my certificates which I am importing it is not showing `jdk` at last of it. please see below

```
Alias name: popcasca
Alias name: verisignclass1g2ca [jdk]
Alias name: comodoaaaca [jdk]
Alias name: geotrustprimarycag2 [jdk]
Alias name: globalsignr3ca [jdk]
```

popcasca is my certificate installed in cacerts but there is no `jdk` mentioned here. What could be the reason for this. Any help.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Your server will be referring to DemoTrust.jks. So just updating cacerts will not help.

You need to remove below line from setDomainEnv[.cmd|.sh].

```
“-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=%WL_HOME%\server\lib\DemoTrust.jks”
```

For more details refer: https://sswaro.wordpress.com/pkix-path-building-failed-in-soa/